# Функция возвращающая список, состоящий из элементов двух списков

Tags: python, функции, list, циклы, коллекции

Всем привет.

Есть два списка:

```
my_list_a = [1, 2, 3]
my_list_b = [11, 22, 33]
```

Для них нужна функция, которая будет принимает в качестве аргументов эти два списка, а возвращает список, состоящий из элементов этих двух списков, при чем первый элемент списка - первый элемент первого аргумента, второй элемент списка - первый элемент второго списка, третий элемент - второй элемент первого списка, четвертый - второй элемент второго аргумента и т.д.

т.е для аргументов [1, 2, 3] и [11, 22, 33] функция должна вернуть:

```
new_list = [1, 11, 2, 22, 3, 33]
```

Приложение моей попытки:

```
my_list_a = [1, 2, 3]
my_list_b = [11, 22, 33]


def list_gen(my_list_a, my_list_b):
 combined_list = [my_list_a, my_list_b] 
 new_list = [i for sublist in combined_list for i in sublist]
 return new_list


print(list_gen(my_list_a, my_list_b))
```

Выводит:

```
new_list = [1, 2, 3, 11, 22, 33]
```

Возможно надо добавить логику в функцию или для это задачи подойдет генераторов последовательностей?

Начал изучать программирование недавно, многих вещей еще не знаю. Буду благодарен, если кто-то объяснит как сделать то, что мне нужно или хотя-бы даст ссылку где можно почитать на тему вопроса. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: приложите ваши попытки по решению задачи

Comment: @maestro, ну, тут и просят объяснить, как сделать. Если вообще непонятно, как браться, то вопрос нормальный:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для параллельного перебора двух и более списков в питоне наиболее удобно использовать функцию `zip`. Фактически, нужно просто добавить к вашему коду в нужном месте вызов этой функции (ну и там ещё скобки поменять), и ваш код будет выдавать то, что нужно.

Comment: Да, спасибо больше за подсказку. Запомню это метод.

>> combined_list = zip(my_list_a, my_list_b)

Comment: @Nikolay `zip` вообще полезная функция и не только по своему прямому назначению бывает используется, но и для других хитрых питоновских трюков :)

Comment: буду углубляться в тему :)

Answer (score 2):

Относительно "объяснит как сделать то, что мне нужно или хотя-бы даст ссылку где можно почитать на тему вопроса.":

Почитайте темы ниже. Это три темы покроют все основные задачи данного упражнения.
Алгоритм простой - из основного кода вызываете функцию и в цикле перебираете аргументы, идя по обоим спискам и формируя финальный список. Изучив материалы ниже, вы должны с этим справиться. Удачи!

Использование списков:
https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/ispolzovanie-spiskov-list-python/

Функции:
https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/opredelenie-funktsij-python/

Циклы:
https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/tsikly-upravlenie-vetvleniem-python/

https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/tsikly-upravlenie-vetvleniem-python/primery-sozdanija-for-in-tsiklov/

P.s. И запомните этот сайт - это основная документация Python. Еще лучше, если на основном сайте читать по-английски:

https://docs.python.org/3.10/

Answer (score 1):

есть очень полезная библиотека, возможно она поможет и вам:

```
from more_itertools import interleave

>>> list(interleave(my_list_a, my_list_b))
# [1, 11, 2, 22, 3, 33]
```

если интересно то [вот](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.interleave) документация